# ASP.NET and VB.NET config files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, app-config

I am trying to share a DLL between an ASP.NET application and a VB.NET (Forms) application.  The client application uses a configuration file to store settings e.g. connection strings and so does the ASP.NET application.

The ASP.NET application uses the System.Web.Configuration namespace whilst the VB.NET application uses the System.Configuration namespace.  I notice that they inherit from the Object class.  I was expecting them both to inherit from a common class so that I could perhaps use Polymorphism to create an instance of the appropriate type in the DLL.

What is the best practice for using config files for DLLs that are shared across ASP.NET and VB.NET applications.  I have researched this and I read somewhere that you should use System.Configuration in the ASP.NET application and I read somewhere else that you should not do this because you cannot write to the web.config if you use System.Configuration in the ASP.NET application.  I do not need to write to the web.config; I need to read it.  What is the best practice?

**Update 13/07/2012**
The DLL contains one class.  The class currently has one constructor, which looks like this:

```
private connectionString As Sub
Public Sub New()
connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString
End Sub
```

I am now thinking about creating another constructor in the class for the none web clients to call i.e. :

```
private connectionString As Sub
Public Sub New()
connectionString = connectionString2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest passing in the arguments to your DLL functions from the hosting application and completely removing the configuration file dependencies from the dll.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question with a potential solution based on your answer.  Is this how you would approach it?

Comment: The configuration file contains other settings that are used by the class e.g. import statements.

Comment: I would, again, remove all configuration file dependancies from the dll.  DLLs are meant to be configuration-free.  The application is the state/config manager and should pass all needed parameters to the dll.  I'd create a public class in the dll called something like `Settings` and take one of those in my object's ctor (or as a parameter to static methods...).  config-dependant dlls are a usability nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

What has worked well for us in this case is we put entries in using:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AccessServer" value="\\apollo\all_access_anon\northwind.mdb" />
    ...
```

And then we access it using:

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string str = appSettings["AccessServer"];
```

That is common to both config files.

Comment: Thanks.  I am able to read the configuration settings using System.Configuration.  I am trying to establish if it is bad practice to use System.Configuration instead of System.Web.Configuration in a none web application i.e. VB.NET.

Comment: I went through this awhile ago - System.Configuration is fine. But for your use, only access those parts of the config file that are common to both.

Comment: Thanks.  What happens then, if there are import statements in the web.config that are relevant to other classes in the ASP.NET application including the class in the DLL file? They are not relevant to the VB.NET application.

Comment: As long as what's in the config file does not violate the schema, you can put anything you want in there. Each program only reads the items it cares about.